# Uploading images from two formsets - Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a page where you can add a product, add a thumbnail, and add images for the product.

I am using to formsets, seen below. The problem is that images uploaded to the image formset are uploaded correctly, but images uploaded to the thumbnail formset are not uploading at all... what might I be doing wrong?

```
def AddProduct(request):

    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(ProductImage,
                                        form=ImageForm, extra=4)
    ThumbnailFormSet = modelformset_factory(ProductvThumbnail,
                                        form=ThumbnailForm)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        product_form = AddEditProductForm(request.POST)
        image_formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='images', 
                               queryset=roductImage.objects.none())
        thumbnail_formset = ThumbnailFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='thumbnail',
                       queryset=ProductThumbnail.objects.none())

        if product_form.is_valid() and image_formset.is_valid() and thumbnail_formset.is_valid():


            product = product_form.save()

            thumbnails = thumbnail_formset.save(commit=False)
            for thumbnail in thumbnails:
                thumbnail.product = product
                thumbnail.save()

            images = image_formset.save(commit=False)
            for image in images:
                image.product = product
                image.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/product/')
        else:
            print (product_form.errors, image_formset.errors, thumbnail_formset.errors)

    else:
        product_form = AddEditProductForm()
        image_formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=ProductImage.objects.none(), prefix='images')
        thumbnail_formset = ThumbnailFormSet(queryset=ProductThumbnail.objects.none(), prefix='thumbnail')

    return render(request, 'product/add.html',
                  {'product_form': product_form, 'image_formset': image_formset,
                   'thumbnail_formset': thumbnail_formset},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution - my formsets seem to be fine, the issue was in my models.py. The ImageField in the ProductThumbnail model was called 'image = models.ImageField...' but it should have been called thumbnail - that is why no thumbnails were being uploaded - my for loop was not finding anything.